# Store objects in an array

Tags: arrays, c++11, object

I'm a 1st year CS student and we recently had an assignment that introduced us to creating our own classes, constructors, and objects. It asked us to go through the following FOR loop and use different objects of our user defined class `planet` to call each user defined function.

```
///put each Obj into an Obj[ ] ----> p[MercuryObj, VenusObj, etc...]
///object objectArray[]
///class_of_object objectArray[]???

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    cout << "The orbit of " << p[i].getName();
    cout << " takes " << p[i].getOrbitPeriod() << " years." << endl;
    cout << "The diameter of " << p[i].getName();
    cout << " is " << p[i].getDiameter() << " km." << endl
    }
```

I thought I could create an array (we aren't using vectors yet) that would hold each object that could then be iterated through in the FOR loop, like an array of type int/float/string/etc ...  but it didn't work
`planet p[] = {MercuryObj, VenusObj, EarthObj, MarsObj};`

Instead, I ended up just manually placing the objects into the array like this

```
planet p[4];
p[0] = MercuryObj;
p[1] = VenusObj;
...
...
```

Someone showed me a different solution:

```
///each value is {planets name, planet's orbit, planet's diameter}
///planet's name is a string, planet's orbit & diameter are both floats  
planet p[4] = {{"Mercury", 2440, 0.387},{"Venus", 6052, 0.723},{"Earth", 6371, 1.000},{"Mars", 3390, 1.524}};
```

but I don't understand how the `.getName()`, `.getOrbitPeriod()`, and `.getDiameter()` would of been able to differentiate each value for the appropriate `.get...()`?

Comment: You should ask your teacher that. You obviously didn't yet grasped one of the C++ concepts (like non-static member functions, or how arrays of objects work, or how array/object initialization works, or something else); any teacher that's worth his/hers salt should be able to find out the subject and give you clarification on it, and do it much better than some back-and-forth in comments can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on "I don't understand how the .getName(), .getOrbitPeriod(), and .getDiameter() would of been able to differentiate each value for the appropriate .get...()?" following:

```
planet p[4] = {{"Mercury", 2440, 0.387},{"Venus", 6052, 0.723},{"Earth", 6371, 1.000},{"Mars", 3390, 1.524}};
```

your question seems to converge into the following rephrase:
"how does a list initialized array know how to construct its constituent objects using nested list initialization?"

see http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization
and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

basically, the compiler knows the type of object that the array will contain. this knowledge was imbued when you declared the array itself as

```
planet p[4] = //...
```

because of this, when it sees each nested brace list, it treats them as if they are a initializer list that goes to the object of that type, and constructs the object in place accordingly. because the array has objects of a type that exposes a "getName()" and "getOrbitPeriod()," etc., then these can be called on each respective object. each respective object in the array maintains its own data consistent with how it was initialized. so, its not that it differentiates between each value, its that when you access p[0] (for example), when you call p[0].getName(), you are calling it on THAT object, which maintains its own data.

Comment: Thank you for rephrasing my question, that coincidentally helped me understand your answer a bit more.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points to upvote the answer but I've marked it as correct

Answer (score 0):

If this is about C++, especially C++11 you should consider using std::array:

```
std::array<planet, 4> p;
```

You can combine that with initializer lists and you can loop over these with much elegance, like this:

```
for(auto &currentPlanet : p)
{
  // ... Do something
}
```

The arrays you are using are from the plain old C standard and not that handy IMHO.

About the initializer lists, it depends on the order how the member variables within the class are declared. You can also overload initializer-lists or use different constructors if you want to control that list, but my guess is, that you don't want to do that really.